# I cant get this email program that I found to work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, email

I found this email program and I can't get it to run. I am using visual studio 2013 c++. I would take any other programs too if you know of any. All I need is to be able to put this in my existing code to email a number to a gmail account. My error is:

error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sending email, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9007: '/Gm' requires '/Zi or /ZI'; option ignored
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\kyle\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sending email\sending email\source.cpp(127): warning C4715: 'MailIt' : not all control paths return a value
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _closesocket@4 referenced in function   "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _connect@12 referenced in function "int   __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _htons@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _recv@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _send@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _socket@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gethostbyname@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSAStartup@8 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSACleanup@0 referenced in function "int __cdecl MailIt(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *)" (?MailIt@@YAHPAD0000@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\kyle\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\sending email\Debug\sending email.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <time.h>

/*If you don't know the mail exchange server for an address for the following
"nslookup -querytype=mx gmail.com" but replace gmail.com with the domain for
whatever email address you want. YOU MUST CHANGE  THESE SETTINGS OR
IT WILL NOT WORK!!! */

#define BUFSIZE 800
#define waittime 500
#define cmailserver "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
#define cemailto "kmtompkinscode@gmail.com"
#define cemailfrom "kmtompkinscode@gmail.com"
#define LogLength 100
#define SMTPLog "smtp.log"
#define cemailsubject "pin"

int MailIt(char *mailserver, char *emailto, char *emailfrom, char *emailsubject,
              char *emailmessage) 
{
    SOCKET sockfd;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    FILE *smtpfile;

    #define bufsize 300
    int bytes_sent;   /* Sock FD */
    int err;
    struct hostent *host;   /* info from gethostbyname */
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;   /* Host Address */
    char line[1000];
    char *Rec_Buf = (char*)malloc(bufsize + 1);
    smtpfile = fopen(SMTPLog, "a+");
    if (WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        fputs("WSAStartup failed", smtpfile);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    if ((host = gethostbyname(mailserver)) == NULL) {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    memcpy(&(dest_addr.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);

    /* Prepare dest_addr */
    dest_addr.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;  /* AF_INET from gethostbyname */
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(25); /* PORT defined above */

    /* Get socket */

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Connect !*/
    fputs("Connecting....\n", smtpfile);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr)) == -1){
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    strcpy(line, "helo me.somepalace.com\n");
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    strcpy(line, "MAIL FROM:<");
    strncat(line, emailfrom, strlen(emailfrom));
    strncat(line, ">\n", 3);
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    strcpy(line, "RCPT TO:<");
    strncat(line, emailto, strlen(emailto));
    strncat(line, ">\n", 3);
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    strcpy(line, "DATA\n");
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    Sleep(waittime);
    strcpy(line, "To:");
    strcat(line, emailto);
    strcat(line, "\n");
    strcat(line, "From:");
    strcat(line, emailfrom);
    strcat(line, "\n");
    strcat(line, "Subject:");
    strcat(line, emailsubject);
    strcat(line, "\n");
    strcat(line, emailmessage);
    strcat(line, "\r\n.\r\n");
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    strcpy(line, "quit\n");
    fputs(line, smtpfile);
    bytes_sent = send(sockfd, line, strlen(line), 0);
    Sleep(waittime);
    err = recv(sockfd, Rec_Buf, bufsize, 0); Rec_Buf[err] = '\0';
    fputs(Rec_Buf, smtpfile);
    fclose(smtpfile);
    #ifdef WIN32
    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    #else
    close(sockfd);
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Please try to understand the error message. It is very verbose at least to me. And this is not C++.

Comment: What do u mean this isnt c++

Comment: It's also not the best formatting I've ever seen:(  The error message is pretty self-explanatory to me.  The C++ compiler doesn't like fopen(), and is moaning about it.

Comment: ya i how would i stop that from giving me a error

Comment: It isn't C++ 'cos it's C.

Comment: so if i put this into a c program it would run

Comment: 'error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To  disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details' - what is unclear about that?

Comment: @kmtompkins Understand that this isn't the compiler issue. The real issue is you aren't paying attention to what compiler is complaining about.

Comment: i know it wants me to put that sould it be #include, define, what?

Comment: i dont believe this is c i tried to make a c program with it and it gave me errors on everything and when i found it on stackoverflow it was tagged a c++

Comment: fopen_s doesn't work with how the person wrote the code i just gives me more errors i already tried that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bout reading an explicit error message.

Comment: @kmtompkins This isn't an online code-writing-assistance service you know. Please take some time to work on your understanding of how do compiler and linker work, perhaps consider reading some C++ tutorials. Then, when you have a clear question that meets the site's standards ([help]) and that wasn't already answered, feel free to post it here.

Comment: i understand how a compiler and link work im just not understanding when the error is coming from because this isnt my code

Comment: Based on the errors currently shown in the question, you need to link to `ws2_32.lib`, and have failed to do so.

Comment: Link to ws2_32 and wsock.. This program also WILL NOT work because emails require SSL/TLS now..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that in the `project setting->C/C++->General` Treat Warnings as Errors was set to "Yes".

To solve it you can set it to "No", And add in `project setting->C/C++->Preprocessor` in `Preprocessor definitions` the `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

**EDIT**

[this link can also help:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: what category would that be under in the settings debugging?

Comment: the treat warnings as errors is off but it still says its a error

Comment: if you have only 1 file you can also define it on the top: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Comment: it missing the `ws2_32.lib` in linker options. you also can add it with `pragma comment` somewhere at the top, like this: `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")`